# Usage of quidquid: "dominetur piscibus aquatilibus ... et quidquid in terra movetur"

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

In Gen. [1:26](https://books.google.com/books?id=2-NUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22denique%20toti%20terrae%22&source=bl&ots=8T_QROkzFR&sig=ACfU3U0nQioxRfkHC6doMXLnuHe4cec4yg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOweSL9q_wAhX7VBUIHeI2B5EQ6AEwBHoECAYQAw#v=onepage&q=%22denique%20toti%20terrae%22&f=false) by Sebastian Castellio:

> ita fatur: Faciamus hominem ad imaginem nostram, nostri similem, qui dominetur piscibus aquatilibus, volucribus aereis, pecudibus, denique toti terrae, **et quidquid in terra movetur**.

Why *quidquid* is not in the dative case like the rest? Also is *...cuicui in terra movetur* correct? or should we add "*qui*", like: *cuicui **quod** in terra moventur*?

Comment: Does the dative *cuicui* even exist? I found no hits in a classical corpus.

Comment: Well, I don't think I have seen it either, but based on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quidquid#Latin) it does exist.

Comment: quidquid is the subject of the relative clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't have a dative be the subject of a clause. *quidquid...movetur* is a new clause. It's something like "rule over...[everything] whatever moves on the land."

You don't need to add anything to the Latin, that's just how the language works. Think in English, "I rule over whatever moves." Do we have a prepositional phrase ("over whatever") with an implied subject? Or is it an implied prepositional phrase with an explicit subject? In Latin, it's the latter, because whenever you start a new clause, you need the subject to be nominative (except in infrequent cases of attraction). The subject of *movetur* is *quidquid*. The dative is implied.

As far as *cuicui* goes, you can't trust Wiktionary. Here is the relevant section in A&G (151.b):

> In **quisquis**, *whoever*, both parts are declined, but the only forms in common use are **quisquis**, **quidquid** (**quicquid**) and **quōquō**.

> [*] Note 1.--Rare forms are **quemquem** and **quibusquibus**; an ablative **quīquī** is sometimes found in early Latin; the ablative feminine **quāquā** is both late and rare. **Cuicui** occurs as a genitive in the phrase **cuicui modī**, of whatever kind. Other cases are cited, but have no authority. In early Latin **quisquis** is occasionally feminine.

You'll often see *cuicui modī* written as one word, *cuicuimodī*. This however is not dative, but genitive.

Comment: thanks! There were probably not so few *quidquid*s I was misreading as accusatives instead of nominative. At any case, apart for their page on *quidquid*, I now see Wiktionary has a [separate page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quisquis#Latin) for *quisquis* that contains many usage notes.

Comment: @d_e I still would trust a more traditional grammar, because at least with those there is editorial control, which Wiktionary lacks, but it seems about right. Be careful too with attestations to early Latin. The spelling conventions were different, so looks can be deceiving.